# Regular expression to extract hashes from file

Tags: php, regex, hash

I have a file in this format:

```
5:Name: {"hash":"c602720140e907d715a9b90da493036f","start":"2016-02-20","end":"2016-03-04"}
5:Name: {"hash":"e319b125d71c62ffd3714b9b679d0624","sa_forum":"on","start":"2015-11-14","end":"2016-02-20"}
```

I am trying to extract the hash key and date using a regular expression.
How can I do it?

I tried this `/^[a-z0-9]{32}$/` for the hash but it doesn't work.

I would appreciate some help.

Edit: This is a text file, and I'm trying to `preg_match()` it. Here's my code:

```
$file = file_get_contents("log.txt");

preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]{32}$/",$file, $hashes);
var_dump($hashes);
```

I get an empty array.

Comment: looks like it's a json...decode it: `json_deocde($string,true);`

Comment: No. its not json. Its a txt file. Trying to preg_match it.

Comment: Please show your code to match it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're bounding your match with `^` and `$`, but you actually want to match something *in the middle* of the string. Try this:

```
/(?<=")[a-f0-9]{32}(?=")/
```

This will only match between the quotes. Also, you don't need `a-z` as it can only be `a-f`.

Also, since you want an array of *all of the hashes in the file* and not just one, you need [`preg_match_all()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
php > $file = file_get_contents("hashfile.txt");
php > preg_match_all('/(?<=")[a-f0-9]{32}(?=")/', $file, $matches);
php > var_dump($matches);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(32) "c602720140e907d715a9b90da493036f"
    [1]=>
    string(32) "e319b125d71c62ffd3714b9b679d0624"
  }
}
php >
```

The matches are stored in the array `$matches[0]` in my above example.